# JSON data from an external file to nvd3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

**Disclaimer:** I am new to d3.
**Problem At Hand:** Pass external `JSON` file to `nvd3` `piechart`

**JSON Data:**

```
[
{
    "Code": "UOU",
    "Result": 8
},
{
    "Code": "HCA",
    "Result": 3
},
{
    "Code": "ACM",
    "Result": 5
},
{
    "Code": "TRG",
    "Result": 1.7
}
]
```

**Code:**

```
var testdata;    
d3.json("../data/testdata.json", function(error, dataSet){
    if(error) return console.warn(error);
    testdata = dataSet;

nv.addGraph function() {
    var width = 500,
        height = 500;

    var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.key })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y })
        .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
        .width(width)
        .height(height);

      d3.select("#test1")
          .datum(testdata)
        .transition().duration(1200)
          .attr('width', width)
          .attr('height', height)
          .call(chart);

    chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

    return chart;
        }
});
```

**My Question:**
What is the best way to bind/parse external `JSON` file to `nvd3`?

What is wrong with this code?

**ERROR:**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function (may not be relevant to databinding, not sure)

Comment: The values for "code" property should be a string enclosed in quotes, isn't?

Comment: "name": value (No JSON parsing required). Using "name": "value" would need something like JSON.parse()

Comment: You've missed the `(` after `nv.addGraph`.

Comment: I already tried that. It would simply not work. Infact error will point to the native nv.d3.js file line no:8419. Thanks for bringing it to the discussion though.